# ZPL - Group Separator in a QR Code reads "IJ"

Tags: printing, qr-code, zpl

I have been trying to print Group Separators using ZPL, but I can't seem to find a way to do that...

I have tried:

- Copy and paste Group Separator directly in ZPL
- Insert Hex of Group Separator (_1D) in ZPL

ZPL Code to reproduce the problem:

```
^XA
^FO100,100^BQN,2,6
^FH^FDA,GS--_1d^FS
^XZ
```

[Online ZPL Emulator Result](http://labelary.com/viewer.html?density=8&width=4&height=6&units=inches&index=0&zpl=%5EXA%0A%5EFO100%2C100%5EBQN%2C2%2C6%0A%5EFH%5EFDA%2CGS-%1D-_1d%5EFS%0A%5EXZ%0A)

It prints a QR-Code, however, we get the following string when we scan the QR-Code:

```
GS-IJ-IJ
```

It seems like ZPL converts Group Separators into "IJ". I have no idea why this is happening, does anyone know how we can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was a problem of the emulator.
When I printed the label using an actual ZPL printer, the code above correctly create QR Code with Group Separators inside.